# Border does not go around full table

Tags: javascript, css, html-table

I have a border that I'm trying to get to go around the full table, but instead it stops at odd places and does not circle the whole table. Looking like this:

[image: https://imgur.com/a/qyNmk]

So as you can see the border stops going around the table in an odd place, so how do I get it to fully encompass the table?

Also due to certain specifications the whole thing must be created with Javascript.

```
function createTable(matrix) {
  var div = document.createElement("div");
  div.style.minWidth = "120px";
  //div.style.height = "100px";
  div.style.top = "0px";
  div.style.left = "0px";
  div.style.zIndex = 1000;
  div.style.background = "grey";
  div.style.color = "white";
  div.style.position = "absolute";

  var header = document.createElement("div");
  header.style.background = "red";
  header.style.textAlign = "center";
  header.innerHTML = "Script Stats";
  div.appendChild(header)

  var x = document.createElement("TABLE");
  //x.style.padding = "50px";

  for (i = 0; i < matrix.length; i++) {
    tableData[i] = [];
    tableData[i][0] = document.createElement("TR");
    x.appendChild(tableData[i][0]);
    for (let k = 0; k < matrix[i].length; k++) {
      var z = document.createElement("TD");
      z.innerHTML = matrix[i][k];
      z.style.textAlign = "center";
      z.style.padding = "5px";
      tableData[i][0].appendChild(z);
    }
  }
  x.style.border = "2px solid white";
  div.appendChild(x);

  var bottom = document.createElement("div");
  bottom.style.background = "red";
  bottom.innerHTML = "Menu";
  bottom.style.textAlign = "center";
  div.appendChild(bottom);

  document.body.appendChild(div);
}
createTable(divTable);
```

Comment: better  show demo

Comment: Create an executable snippet using enough code to reproduce your problem, instead of linking an image. Images are not helpful.

Comment: what is `divTable`...its showing error....`divTable` in not defined

Comment: Do you mean the white border?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I reproduced your problem, and 
a simple solution to your problem is

```
<style>
 table { border-collapse: collapse; }
</style>
```

you can see it in action here : 
https://jsbin.com/jenupigupe/edit?html,js,output

Comment: So what effect did this have on table ?